# import matplotlib.pyplot hangs

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-import

I'm trying to get matplotlib up and running on OS X 10.8.4. I've installed matplotlib and the dependencies (libping, freetype, numpy, scipy). I am able to import matplotlib just fine. However, if I try to import matplotlib.pyplot, it just hangs. There's no error, it's just that nothing happens.

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot
```

...I've waited maybe 20 minutes an nothing happens. I'm using version 1.2.1, but even uninstalled that and tried version 1.2.0, but to no avail. I've seen a number of questions on SO about import errors with matplotlib.pyplot, but nothing where it just hangs. I then tried to get it working using the Enthought/Canopy python distribution, but again, the same hanging issue. Here's what I see if I kill the import:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.3.1262.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 26, in <module>
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure, figaspect
  File "/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.3.1262.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 34, in <module>
    import matplotlib.colorbar as cbar
  File "/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.3.1262.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 29, in <module>
    import matplotlib.collections as collections
  File "/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.3.1262.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py", line 23, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backend_bases as backend_bases
  File "/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.3.1262.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 37, in <module>
    import matplotlib.widgets as widgets
  File "/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.3.1262.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/widgets.py", line 17, in <module>
    from lines import Line2D
  File "/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.3.1262.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/lines.py", line 25, in <module>
    from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
  File "/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.3.1262.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1335, in <module>
    _rebuild()
  File "/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.3.1262.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1322, in _rebuild
    fontManager = FontManager()
  File "/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.3.1262.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 980, in __init__
    self.ttffiles = findSystemFonts(paths) + findSystemFonts()
  File "/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.3.1262.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 317, in findSystemFonts
    for f in get_fontconfig_fonts(fontext):
  File "/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.3.1262.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 274, in get_fontconfig_fonts
    output = pipe.communicate()[0]
  File "/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.3.1262.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 746, in communicate
    stdout = _eintr_retry_call(self.stdout.read)
  File "/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.3.1262.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 478, in _eintr_retry_call
    return func(*args)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

The output was the same when I was using the default python 2.7 that comes with OS X.

#### UPDATE

Allowing `import matplotlib.pyplot` to run for a few hours and then interrupting the import now gives me this output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 26, in <module>
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure, figaspect
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 34, in <module>
    import matplotlib.colorbar as cbar
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 29, in <module>
    import matplotlib.collections as collections
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py", line 23, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backend_bases as backend_bases
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 37, in <module>
    import matplotlib.widgets as widgets
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/widgets.py", line 17, in <module>
    from lines import Line2D
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/lines.py", line 25, in <module>
    from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1335, in <module>
    _rebuild()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1322, in _rebuild
    fontManager = FontManager()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 980, in __init__
    self.ttffiles = findSystemFonts(paths) + findSystemFonts()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 324, in findSystemFonts
    files = list_fonts(path, fontexts)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 171, in list_fonts
    return cbook.listFiles(directory, pattern)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook.py", line 944, in listFiles
    for dirname, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 284, in walk
    if isdir(join(top, name)):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py", line 41, in isdir
    st = os.stat(s)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Does anyone know what the recursive `for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):` might indicate?

Comment: What if you explicitly set the backend to 'agg' and try? ``import matplotlib matplotlib.use('AGG') import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`` You won't be able to use ``show`` but it may diagnose if this is a backend problem?

Comment: @BeRecursive Thanks. I just tried that but have the same problem when I run `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.

Comment: OK. Open up a terminal and run ``fc-list`` as root. Does this take a long time?

Comment: Out of interest, do you have a large number of custom fonts, or custom font directories? http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/get-fontconfig-fonts-td37664.html

Comment: @BeRecursive Just checked `fc-list` and that hangs just like `import matplotlib.pyplot`. I just have the default fonts that come with OS X.

Comment: Ok, let that fc-list run - what it's doing is building some sort of massive cache. Once that finishes running, matplotlib should, in theory, use that cache and start working.

Comment: Thanks. Still running. Will get back when it finishes.

Comment: @BeRecursive your `fc-list` suggestion seemed very promising and I was able to create the cache, but unfortunately the `matplotlib.pyplot` problem persists. I'm updating the question above with more info.

Answer (score 92):

You can fix the problem on Mac OS X Mavericks and Yosemite by doing the following:

```
cd ~/.matplotlib/
fc-list  # Should take a couple minutes.
```

After `fc-list` finishes running you will be able to import the package using `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`. This is the [github issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2919) with the solution. It seems the bug is related to the font cache.

Comment: Worked on Yosemite as well.

Comment: Worked on El Capitan as well (and still necessary).

Comment: My `~/.matplotlib/` is empty.  Does that get populated as a pip install of matplotlib?

Answer (score 3):

I figured out what was happening. Hopefully the solution is useful to others. In the `/usr/X11/lib` folder there was a symbolic link for the directory that was pointing back to itself. This appears to have created an infinite loop. When I removed the link, the import worked.

Comment: I have the same issue but do not see any symbolic link in /usr/X11/lib  Can you expand this answer ?

Comment: I am having the same problem. Can you be more specific. What was the name of that directory?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem on Linux.

Turned out matplotlib was having some issues figuring out the GUI backend to use.

Explicitly saying it to use Tkinter background - which it does by default, using the following command resolved the issue:

```
%matplotlib tk
```

This followed by import

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

worked as expected.

Comment: I tried this, the import works fine but then `plt.figure()` leads to hanging