# plt.show() hangs on OSX with Anaconda Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
plt.show()
```

...crickets.  The interpreter hangs and I can't seem to interrupt it.

This is with Python 2.7.9 and Anaconda 2.2.0 (x86_64) on OSX.

Does this happen for anyone else?  How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure it's `plt.show()` that hangs and not the import? Because there's an issue with the font cache on OS X which is addressed in the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490444/import-matplotlib-pyplot-hangs).

Comment: The import works fine, and so far as I can tell, so does everything else.  The hang definitely happens with `plt.show()`

Comment: It runs fine with me, it took a few seconds before the window popped up. Do you use interactive or non-interactive mode? And what is your back-end? Do you run these lines from a script in the command line, or do you type them in the python interpreter? In my experience with OS-X, windows created from the command line often do not rise to the front. Could it be that the plot window is created behind other windows or hidden in a corner?

Comment: Nope - no window anywhere.  The backend is 'MacOSX'.  Definitely hangs.

Comment: Ah, @titusjan makes an excellent point. Now that he mentioned the backend, I remember that I once had a similar issue that was resolved once I changed the backed to `backend: TkAgg` in my `~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc`. You may want to give that a shot as well if using `pythonw` isn't too convenient for you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try starting Python using `pythonw` instead of `python`.

Comment: I don't know why this worked, but it did.  Thank you!

Comment: On OS X, you need to use `pythonw` whenever you use something that hooks into the OS X windowing system (such as matplotlib), as it needs to "trick" OS X into thinking it is a Framework (using the `python.app` package that you'll find in the `anaconda` directory).

Comment: Another thing that should work is to use `ipython`, as it uses python.app automatically.

Comment: Using `ipython` worked for me, thanks @asmeurer. For scripts, I changed the hashbang line to `#!/usr/bin/env ipython` and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely an issue with your backend setting. If you want your plots to show up inline (inside of your notebook) import with this added line:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
```

To have your plots show up interactively inline (inside your notebook) import with this line instead:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook
```

To have your plots show up outside of your notebook (in a new window), import with this line instead:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib qt
```

**NOTE:** You need to restart the kernel to switch between inline notebook and outside qt to avoid the error: *Warning: Cannot change to a different GUI toolkit*

Finally, if issues persist, the following might help uncover what is going on:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.get_backend()
```

If using any of the options above, it should output one of the following:

- 'module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline'
- 'nbAgg'
- 'Qt4Agg'

Answer (score 0):

Modify `matplotlib.pyplot` import to:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg') #----> Specify the backend
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this in the beginning of your iPython:

```
% pylab inline
```