# matplotlib.show() hangs into an infinite loop

Tags: matplotlib, anaconda, python-3.5

Note: please dont mark it as duplicate, the previous question doesnt answer it completely.

This question has been answered partially in this link: 
    [plt.show() hangs on OSX with Anaconda Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30086663/plt-show-hangs-on-osx-with-anaconda-python?noredirect=1&lq=1)

However, there is no mention of where does the matplotlibrc resides to change the option. Also, specially when we are invoking the notebook using ipython notebook command, where can we use pythonw to overcome the issue?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For me (W10 x64), the matplotlibrc resides in the folder

C:\Program Files\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data

It is just a text file you can edit with any editor to change the options.
What worked (but I'm really not understanding all of this) was the following config (line 38 and following):

```
backend      :  Qt4Agg 

# If you are using the Qt4Agg backend, you can choose here
# to use the PyQt4 bindings or the newer PySide bindings to
# the underlying Qt4 toolkit.

#backend.qt4 : PyQt4        # PyQt4 | PySide
```

commenting this last line was necessary to finally have any curve plotted.

For your second question, I'm sorry I can't help at all.

I hope this will help you, good luck !

Comment: One more thing :
When trying to plot in the debug mode, matplotlib failed systematically.
Some solutions are described to this specific question, but it could help you too :
either run your script in a dedicated interpreter, or simply add plt.pause(1) after plotting in the debug mode.