# Unable to import matplotlib.animation

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I'm new to both python and OSX, so if i'm not understanding super basic stuff please forgive me.

I'm using python 2.7.12 on a fresh install from Homebrew. I also used Homebrew to install ipython, ffmpeg and libav (installs avconv, which I believe is required for what i'm trying to do).

- I've used pip to install Scipy, numpy (which I think comes with scipy anyway?) and matplotlib
- I'm running El Capitan v10.11.6

Background (for some context):
I'm running some hydrodynamic simulations that output a bunch of binary files. I wan't to stitch them together to create a movie. Lucky for me, one of my colleagues has already written a tidy little python script to do so (which he wrote in ipython).

Problem:
When trying to run

```
import matplotlib.animation
```

The script just hangs, and matplotlib animation never gets imported. I've tried changing the backend via

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('tkagg')
import matplotlib.animaton
```

I've tried various backends that I got by running code from [List of all available matplotlib backends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091993/list-of-all-available-matplotlib-backends)

I have also tried [import matplotlib.pyplot hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490444/import-matplotlib-pyplot-hangs) (updating fc-lists)

Lastly, and i'm not sure if this is helpful, but leaving ipython trying to import matplot.animation for about 10 minutes, and then terminating it outputs the following

```
In [3]: import matplotlib.animation
^C---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-64e90e455a86> in <module>()
----> 1 import matplotlib.animation

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py in <module>()
    589
    590 @writers.register('imagemagick')
--> 591 class ImageMagickWriter(MovieWriter, ImageMagickBase):
    592     def _args(self):
    593         return ([self.bin_path(),

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py in wrapper(writerClass)
     73     def register(self, name):
     74         def wrapper(writerClass):
---> 75             if writerClass.isAvailable():
     76                 self.avail[name] = writerClass
     77             return writerClass

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py in isAvailable(cls)
    284                              stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    285                                      creationflags=subprocess_creation_flags)
--> 286             p.communicate()
    287             return True
    288         except OSError:

    /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/ lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc in communicate(self, input)
    798             return (stdout, stderr)
    799
--> 800         return self._communicate(input)
    801
    802

    /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc in _communicate(self, input)
   1417                 stdout, stderr =     self._communicate_with_poll(input)
   1418             else:
-> 1419                 stdout, stderr =     self._communicate_with_select(input)
   1420
   1421             # All data exchanged.  Translate lists into strings.

/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc in _communicate_with_select(self, input)
   1518             while read_set or write_set:
   1519                 try:
-> 1520                     rlist, wlist, xlist =     select.select(read_set, write_set, [])
   1521                 except select.error, e:
   1522                     if e.args[0] == errno.EINTR:

KeyboardInterrupt:
```

If you give any of this a second thought, even if you aren't able to help, thank you very much!

Comment: What commands did you use to install the plugins? Do you get the same result if you run if from a script as if you run it from the prompt?

Comment: By plugins do you mean matplotlib etc? I used pip to install those. Eg,
pip install matplotlib.


And yes, if I run the script via navigating to the folder and doing python script.py, it hangs on the import line just the same as it does through ipython, or if I just input it in the prompt

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment? Or did you need to do `sudo pip install ...`? Also, have you tried the normal python? I.e. not ipython.

Comment: Also, could you edit your question with the result of you doing `pip freeze`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have more than one version of Python installed? I would check your python path. Make sure matplotlib is in 2.7 in this case.

This might be relevant too -- [import matplotlib.pyplot hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490444/import-matplotlib-pyplot-hangs)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I when I originally encountered this issue I also had python installed via anaconda2. I have since removed that via using the conda-clean 'thing' (https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install#os-x-uninstall).

My python path is as follows: 

    PYTHONPATH=~/usr/local/lib/python2.7:$PYTHONPATH

Comment: with export PYTHONPATH after that

Comment: It appears that there may have been an issue with my PATH and PYTHONPATH (the syntax I used was incorrect).

Comment: I had a similar issue with anaconda in the past. The issue is resolved then?

Comment: Somewhat (apologies for the late reply)
I have to change my PYTHON to /usr/bin/python2.7 if I want to be able to run my script with python script.py. I then have the issue that I can't use ipython (as I've installed ipython through homebrew).

I haven't been able to find a more permanent fix as of yet