# Matplotlib is hanging when using python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Matplotlib hangs now that I've upgraded to Sierra.

The behavior is different depending on how I run it.

**In a file** (running with `%run <filename>` inside of ipython or `python <file name>` from the terminal):
The terminal will hang on import (`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`) and all I get is the little rocket icon bouncing in my dock.

**Directly from ipython**:
I can import it and show a plot, but it will hang once I try to close the figure window. Doing this from inside of the basic python shell does not have this problem. So it seems running in interactive mode also causes hanging.

Has anyone experienced something similar?

python version: 3.5.2
matplotlib version: 1.5.1
backend: MacOSX
OSX: 10.12.2

Switching to a TkAgg backend will display the figure window, but it will hang on plotting (in interactive mode).

**Note**
Setting up a virtual environment to run python 2.7 with a TkAgg backend works as expected

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems to be a caching issue:

running:

```
cd ~/.matplotlib
fc-list
```

fixed the problem (same issue discussed here: [import matplotlib.pyplot hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490444/import-matplotlib-pyplot-hangs) but the symptoms were a little different)